# Easy way to git diff two different repos

Tags: git, laravel

I've been doing a lot of quick easy laravel tutorials lately.  I'd like to be able to see only the changes that were made to the files, like a git diff. I cloned both the laravel project and the completed tutorial, then deleted all of the files in the fresh laravel directory except for the git files, then copied over the completed tutorial files into the fresh install folder and did a git diff.  I googled a bunch, but didn't really find what I was looking for. There's got to be a better way to do this? Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Next time you start a tutorial, check the original state into Git when you start (`git init && git add . && git commit -m 'initial import'`). Thus, any changes you make will be trackable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add one repository to another as a remote, and use `git diff another/master..master` to diff.

I think the best way to learn it is clone repository and create a new branch to commit all changes.

To achieve this goal right now, you could use `git rebase --onto another/master base master`.